# Ajax call with module helper

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

Is is possible to handle ajax calls in Joomla without using a component helper?

For example; I want to create a module that makes ajax calls. I know how to handle the call using a component helper (index.php?option=com_myhelper....&format=raw), but instead of a component helper I would like to make this from the module.

Is there some way to call Joomla modules, the same way as you would call a Joomla component from an outside script (http://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_myhelper....&format=raw) ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to call an AJAX function from domainA to domainB?
If so, you have to use a proxy.

What I did, maybe can help:

JS of the component:

```
J.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/index.php',
    data: {
        option: 'com_mycomponent',
        task: 'getTaskFromTheController',
        param: 'paramValue1'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        J('#suggestions').fadeIn();
        J('#suggestions').html(data);
        J('#suggestions .close-image').click(function() {
            J('#suggestions').fadeOut();                    
        });     
    }
```

More info about [jQuery POST/GET](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Add in the controller.php of the component the function getTaskFromTheController

```
public function getTaskFromTheController()
{
    global $mainframe;
    $model =& $this->getModel();
    // If GET 
    // $param= JRequest::getVar('param');

    // If POST 
    // $param = JRequest::getVar('param', '', 'post', 'string');
    //Or
    // $param = JRequest::getVar('param', '', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML);

    echo $model->getUserTaskAjax($param);
    $mainframe->close();
}
```

Interesting links:
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2424982
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_AJAX_to_your_component
[How to use jQuery ajax in Joomla module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379961/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-in-joomla-module)

Comment: Is is possible to use a module as proxy instead of a component?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the Joomla! module workflow was not designed for that purpose (Correct me if I'm wrong). But you can create a proxy.php file and you can include the Joomla! framework [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445549/how-to-get-current-joomla-user-with-external-php-script

Comment: That's my conclusion as well. The tip with the standalone php-file that includes the framework is worth looking into a bit more. Great tip, thanks!